# "Predefined type 'System.*' is not defined or imported" Error, visual studio code, omnisharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I'm having an issue with the mentioned error in several .net core applications. I'm using vs code version 1.18.0 but the error started to appear already in the previous version.

The error appears in every .cs file for every datatype like string, int, void etc. and also for class imports.

All the projects still compile and run properly. Also on another workstation I'm **not** having the issue in the same projects, so it seems to be a local omnisharp/ vs code or windows? problem.

Has anyone had something like this and managed to fix it or any suggestions on what i could try?

I've reinstalled vs code and omnisharp already, but I'm still having the problem.

**example Error:**
*Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [GG]*

Comment: What is your .NET Core version? How did you install it? What does `dotnet --info` say?

Comment: I have the same isue and my .net core version is 2.0.2, vscode 1.18.0 on windows 10.
-- 
Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.2
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a04b4bf512

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

Comment: reported here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1855

Comment: .NET-Befehlszeilentools (2.0.2)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.2
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a04b4bf512

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

(the first entry is the .net core sdk )

Comment: i installed it over microsofts portal via installer, had no issues for the first two months, also i can not tell exactly when the error started to appear, i was working on a frontend app that didn't include any .cs files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a fix ( or workaround) for my problem:

***short version***: I changed the omnisharp msbuild instance by **uninstalling Visual Studio 2017 Pro**.

***long version***: A few months ago I installed VS 2017 Pro to check out the features, used it for 2 weeks in trial mode and forgot about it for several months.

Around one week ago I opened it (by accident :D) and got a notification, that my trial period expired, also VS locked itself.
It didn't bother me , because I wasn't using it. In @VahidN 's Link I found out that omnisharp is using "the most native" msbuild instance that is installed, which in my case was the one of the locked VS 2017 Pro. 1+1 I unsinstalled VS and I'm good.

I'll reinstall VS 2017 ( Comunity) and post a comment if it still works fine.

**EDIT:**: I reinstalled VS 2017, everything works fine, so the **actual solution is updating VS 2017**, which i couldnt do besause it was locked prieviously.

Comment: In my case w/ Mac OSX, I just had to go to Visual Studio installer and update. It seems like somehow VSCode interacts with Visual Studio's mono and .NET framework versions. After updating and clean/restore projects, it was good to go.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Same was my case. Uninstall VS 2019 community solved.

For me Azure function will run by func start on command. But the code misguides there is error

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for sharing your fix. Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. What worked for me is to reinstall the latest OmniSharp.

Copy-pasted from this [ticket](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2295):

> The fix for this has been pushed into OmniSharp. You should be able to get the fix by setting the "omnisharp.path" option in VS Code to "latest". That will cause C# for VS Code to download the latest build OmniSharp at start up.